# Creating a list with empty objects

Tags: r

Consider this code:

```
uniques <- unique(datamelt$dates)
R<-list(rep("NA", length(uniques)))
```

this will create

```
str(R)
List of 1
 $ : chr [1:1208] "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA" ...
```

However, i want something like

```
R1<-list(NA,NA,NA)
str(R1)
List of 3
 $ : logi NA
 $ : logi NA
 $ : logi NA
```

Because the empty objects will be filled with dataframes created during a loop through [datamelt]

How can i create a list of [uniques] without writing a command including infinite "NAs" (in this case 1208)?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `lapply(seq(1208), function(x) NA)` but maybe better to do `vector(mode = "list", length = 1208)`

Comment: you could also use: `R <- list(); is.na(R) <- 1:3` which is slightly more explicic than `vector()` (though I prefer the `vector()` solution above)

Comment: You could also use `replicate(3, NA, simplify=FALSE)` or `rep(list(NA),3)`